# Can't upgrade jquery 1.4.4 to jquery 1.6.4

Tags: jquery, .net, signalr, package-managers

i'm trying to upgrade my siganlr from 2.0.0 beta to 2.0.0 from package manager console ,but im getting the following error :

Install-Package : Updating 'jQuery 1.4.4' to 'jQuery 1.6.4' failed. Unable to find a version of 'jQuery.UI.Effects.Core' that i s compatible with 'jQuery 1.6.4'.

Any idea ?

Comment: You probably need to upgrade jquery-ui as well.